# SQL query for finding different records in succesive rows of the same column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL database of morphologically parsed (analyzed) texts. Every row contains data of succesive words from a text. Columns describe the morphology of the word. So, for instance, column 3 is for grammatical gender; column 4 for grammatical number, 5 is for Tense, and so on.

```
WORD   POSITION_IN_TEXT   GENDER   NUMBER   TENSE
aaa           1           M          P          ø
bbb           2           F          P          ø
ccc           3           ø          P          F
```

How do I build a query in SQL or SQLite to find all instances where a Word X with GENDER "M" is followed by word x+1 with NUMBER "P" and by word x + 2 with TENSE "F"?

Comment: What is "x"?  I don't follow your question.

Comment: x is for the position in text. (i.e. word 1, 2, 3, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following particularly well I'll admit, but this sounds like a window function using `lead` so I'll have a stab. It requires an ordering criteria and I am assuming your sample data is not correct with all words having `position_in_text=1`, surely this should be incrementing by each word position?

```
   select Word, Position_In_Text, Gender, Number, Tense
    from (
      select *, 
        lead(number,1) over(order by position_in_text) NextNumber,
        lead(Tense,2)  over(order by position_in_text) NextTense
      from table
      where gender='M'
    )x
    where NextNumber='P' and NextTense='F'
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Stu. Your guess was right. I edited the text to correct the typo in the original quuestion. Now I need to study your answer. Thanks!!